# Выборка рубрик и группировка по вложенности

Tags: mysql, выборка

Здравствуйте.
Есть в базе MySQL таблица рубрик, у каждой записи есть title, parent_id и id. Причём, если parent_id=0, то рубрика первого уровня, а если parent_id = какому-нибудь id, то эта рубрика вложена в другую рубрику по соответствующему id:

```
id | parent_id | title  
1  | 0         | Корневая рубрика 1  
2  | 0         | Корневая рубрика 2  
3  | 0         | Корневая рубрика 3 
15 | 1         | Подрубрика 15 в рубрике 1  
16 | 1         | Подрубрика 16 в рубрике 1  
17 | 3         | Подрубрика 17 в рубрике 3 
18 | 2         | Подрубрика 18 в рубрике 2 
19 | 1         | Подрубрика 19 в рубрике 1
```

Вопрос: нужно вывести список с рубриками и подрубриками вот в таком виде:

```
Корневая рубрика 1  
- Подрубрика 15  
- Подрубрика 16  
- Подрубрика 19  
Корневая рубрика 2  
- Подрубрика 18  
Корневая рубрика 3  
- Подрубрика 17
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить SELECT-запрос? Спасибо.

Comment: У вас только 2 уровня вложенности ? И я правильно понимаю, что вам достаточно только правильно отсортировать записи, что бы они шли в указанном вами порядке (ибо "-" в начале строки вы можете сами дорисовать видя то parent_id не 0)

Comment: @Mike пока только 2 уровня, насчёт больше, пока не решено, возможно и будет. Да, достаточно просто в правильном порядке отсортировать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для одного уровня вложенности:

```
select *
  from Table1
 order by if(parent_id=0,id,parent_id), id
```

Если уровней больше - то вам стоит подумать о смене БД, потому как MySQL практически единственная из СУБД не умеющая работать с иерархическими структурами. Либо реализовать логику построения дерева на клиенте.

[Тест на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19462a/2)